# Difference between two Arrays C# (Random input + User input)

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, difference

I've created an array which generate 10 random numbers, and I want it to be compared to user input of 10 numbers. If 6 numbers are equal to the random generated numbers (from 1 to 25) then it should show a 6.

Also, the order should not matter. If the user input the number 8 as his or her first selection, it should be able to be compared to the random generated number if it generated number 8 as its last selection. Which in the end should show the result of minimum 1.

```
        Random r = new Random();
    int MyRandomNr = r.Next(1, 26);
    // Random Generator

    var ArrayRandom = new int[] { MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr, MyRandomNr };

    Console.Write("HELLO AND WELCOME!"
    + System.Environment.NewLine + "Type in 10 numbers."
    + System.Environment.NewLine + "A number between from 1 to 25, one number at the time " + System.Environment.NewLine);


    string[] ArrayUser = new string[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write((i + 1) + ". Next number is: ");
        ArrayUser [i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I've looked through the Stackoverflow and the following code doesn't really compare the two arrays in the way I want it to compare to each other. The following code works more like an exam, but I'm looking for something similar to this...

```
            int[] answer = { 1, 3, 4};
            int[] exam = { 4, 1, 3};

            int correctAnswers = 0;
            int wrongAnswers = 0;

            for (int index = 0; index < answer.Length; index++)
            {
                if (answer[index] == exam[index])
                {
                    correctAnswers += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    wrongAnswers += 1;
                }
            }

            Console.Write("The matching numbers are " + correctAnswers +
                "\n" + "The non matching numbers are " + wrongAnswers);
```

Comment: It generates 1 random number added 10 times in the array

Comment: @Martin Isn't it clear? I want to know how to compare two arrays and get the difference.

Comment: @Martin I've looked on this forum trying to find the answer, but I only found getting the result if the first two elements are equal. Not if the first element is equal to the second element. Therefore I'm asking the question...

Comment: Why not simply sort both arrays first? By the way, " in the end should show the result of minimum 1" - why would that be?